# display an alert message if an option is selected while selecting other option

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, reactjs, jquery-ui

**displaying an alert message when selecting an option jQuery**

> if any of the ports has selected(rate == "MAC"), an alert message should be displayed when selecting MAX in other ports 
> if any of the ports has selected(rate == "MAX") an alert message should be displayed when selecting MAC in other ports
> If MAC is selected then you cannot select MAX in any of the other select boxes and vice versa. An alert message should be displayed

```
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Port</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="port">1</td>
      <td>
        <select class= rate>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">MAC</option>
          <option value="2">MAX</option>
          <option value="3">MIN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="port">2</td>
      <td>
        <select class= rate>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">MAC</option>
          <option value="2">MAX</option>
          <option value="3">MIN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="port">3</td>
      <td>
        <select class= rate>
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">MAC</option>
          <option value="2">MAX</option>
          <option value="3">MIN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

$(document).ready(function() {
$("select.rate").change(function() {
    var rate = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
    var this_ = $(this)
    $("select.rate").not(this).each(function() {
        var values = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
        if (rate == 'MAC' && values == 'MAX') {
            alert("Since you have selected MAC, you can't select MAX");
            this_.val("") 
            return false; 
        }
    })

});
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `.each` loop to iterate through all select-boxes and check if the text of option is same or not depending on this show your message and reset that select-box.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("select.rate").change(function() {
    var rate = $(this).find("option:selected").text(); //get option text
    var this_ = $(this)
    //loop through other slects but not the one where change has occur
    $("select.rate").not(this).each(function() {
      var values = $(this).find("option:selected").text();
      //compare... 
      if (rate == 'MAC' && values == 'MAX') {
        alert("Since you have selected MAX, you can't select MAC");
        this_.val("") //reset
        return false; //break through loop
      }
      if (rate == 'MAX' && values == 'MAC') {
        alert("Since you have selected MAC, you can't select MAX")
        this_.val("")
        return false;

      }
    })

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Port</th>
      <th>Rate</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="port">1</td>
      <td>
        <select class="rate">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">MAC</option>
          <option value="2">MAX</option>
          <option value="3">MIN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="port">2</td>
      <td>
        <select class="rate">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">MAC</option>
          <option value="2">MAX</option>
          <option value="3">MIN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="port">3</td>
      <td>
        <select class="rate">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="1">MAC</option>
          <option value="2">MAX</option>
          <option value="3">MIN</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: if(rate == 'MAC' && value == 'MAX') then alert ("Since you have selected MAC, you can't select MAX") } Something like this? could you help me with this ? Thank you.

Comment: why you have change your question again ?

Comment: I'm sorry but the initial question was the same that I asked. Maybe I thought the question was a little misleading that's why I edited it. I want to display an alert message when the first box selects MAC and if trying to select MAX in other select boxes then display an alert.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you very much!